# Stream webcam to RMTP server via HTML5?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, webcam

is the following possible: stream webcam **directly** to rtmp server via the browser/html5.

- I have a webcam
- I have a Vimeo Live RMTP url

What I'm doing now is Opening OBS Studio and configuring it all and that works.

But what I want is that I open my browser, accept that the browser may open my webcam and in the background the RTMP url is configured already so my webcam streams to the RMTP url.

The only thing I find is that I need FFMPEG running on my server to send this all through. Is that still the only way in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can not stream RTMP. Yes the only way to do it is with a service in he middle.